# PHP 5.4 How to include OCX file

Tags: php, com, xampp, ocx, dcom

I have installed latest XAMPP having PHP 5.4 on windows 7.
I am looking to use OCX file using PHP, I successfully registered it using regsvr32 command.
At the same time following settings are enabled in php.ini file

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
com.allow_dcom = true
com.autoregister_typelib = true
com.autoregister_casesensitive = false
com.autoregister_verbose = true
```

Follwing php code I am using to use it.

```
$moo = new COM("Ranger.ocx");
```

Getting error as

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed
>   to create COM object `Ranger.ocx': Invalid syntax ' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\com\index.php:9 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\com\index.php(9): com->com('Ranger.ocx') #1 {main}
>   thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\com\index.php on line 9

Please provide valid solution to resolve this issue.
Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All OCX files depend by vbruntime6.dll.
OCS is a dependency of Visual Basic 6, is not native dinamic library of system operative.